# Github pages' jekyll creates 1 line HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, github-actions, github-pages

I am using Github pages to deploy a static website built using jekyll.
The porject was forked from https://academicpages.github.io/ (I am a beginner in all of this)

For some reason, the "local" (on my machine) behavior of jekyll and the "remote" (i.e. using Github Actions) behavior are different :

Remotely, the built HTML files are 1-liners.
This is quite annoying since Javascript comments (starting with \ and ending at the end of the line) are all over the place.

This undesirable behavior is not present locally.

How can I make configure the jekyll from github pages to behave the same locally and remotely ?

Cheers,

Gabriel

Comment: Note to self: I could use the comments /* ... */. Is there a better way ?

Comment: No, that's exactly one of the instructions for compression, as it's entirely liquid based: https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/docs/configuration/#html-compression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the [compress_html](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml#L308) plugin in the production config. The [dev config](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io/blob/master/_config.dev.yml) doesn't have this so it doesn't minify locally. You could remove the plugin entirely or experiment with options to fit your needs.

Comment: If you intend to completely disable compression for whatever reason, you need not to remove/comment out the directive that may be in your root template (`default.html`).